# how to find the approver details in manual validation task of azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using ManualValidation@0 task in my azure pipeline. i need to get the details of the user who will reject/resume. How to get the details?

code:

```
- task: ManualValidation@0
      displayName: 'Waiting for approval'
      condition: eq(variables.Test_Result_Status, 'Red')
      timeoutInMinutes: 1400 # task times out in 24 hours
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          XYZ@abc.com
        instructions: |
          resume/reject Pipeline.
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Users with **Queue builds** permission on the pipeline can resume or reject the run.

Actually , the email or group you define in this task just receive notifications.
reference :

1. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/restrict-approver-list-in-manual-validation-task-i/1692413
2. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines#:~:text=Users%20with%20Queue%20builds%20permission%20on%20the%20pipeline%20can%20resume%20or%20reject%20the%20run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines#:%7E:text=Users%20with%20Queue%20builds%20permission%20on%20the%20pipeline%20can%20resume%20or%20reject%20the%20run)

Regards ,
Jean Yves